# Grouping values into lists based on parent list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nested, python-2.x

I have a list that I am trying to compare to a sequential combination of values in two other lists. The code below works, but the output values are in a single, flat list.

```
values = [3,6,7,8]
list1 = [2,5]
list2 = [4,8]
main = []

for i in values:
    for x,y in zip(list1, topElevation):
        if x<i<y:
            main.append(i)
>>>[3,6,7]
```

How can I organize the script so that it splits the values into multiple lists such that the first nested list takes all the values of `list1[0]<i<list2[0]`, the second `list1[1]<i<list2[1]`, and so on... (through `list1[n]<i<list2[n]`)? In that case, the output would be:

```
>>>[[3],[6,7]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).
You can use it here:

```
values = [3,6,7,8]
list1 = [2,5]
list2 = [4,8]

print [[i for i in values if x<i<y] for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Or changing your code a little bit:

```
main = []

for x,y in zip(list1, list2):
    mid = []
    for i in values:
        if x<i<y:
            mid.append(i)
    main.append(mid)

print main
```

Output in both cases:

```
[[3], [6, 7]]
```

Comment: Helpful to have the list comprehension next to the full version for comparison's sake. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [List Comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) with a [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to do this:

```
>>> [filter(lambda x: l < x < r, values) for l, r in zip(list1, list2)]
[[3], [6, 7]]
```

Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]`

So equivalent solution：

```
>>> [[item for item in values if l < item < r] for l, r in zip(list1, list2)]
[[3], [6, 7]]
```

---

Details:

> **filter(function, iterable)**
>
> Construct a `list` from those elements of `iterable` for which function returns true. `iterable` may be either a `sequence`, a `container` which *supports iteration*, or an iterator.

Comment: it's too much for a beginner, i added list comprehension version to my answer without filter/lambda

Comment: I thought I've given enough docs on those. BTW, I don't think it's too much to learn.

Comment: that's why you copied my solution :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create empty list and put number into this list before you append it to `main`. And you have to use `for` loops in different order.

```
values = [3,6,7,8]
list1 = [2,5]
list2 = [4,8]
main = []


for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
    temp = []
    for i in values:
        if x<i<y:
            temp.append(i)
    main.append(temp)

print(main)
```

Comment: I saw you answer after I press `Save`

Comment: @minitoto `lambda` and `filter` are nice but hard to explain to beginner :)